# Pass and get parameters in react navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios, react-android

how can I pass and get parameters in react navigation?
I have tried

```
 this.props.navigation.getParams('name',defaultValue)
```

to get the parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get param:

```
const name = props.route.params.name
```

pass params:

```
navigation.navigate({
  name: 'RouteName',
  params: {
      name: 'nameParam'
  }
})
```

or:

```
navigation.navigate('RouteName', {name: 'nameParam'})
```